# setTimeout not working when used for svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to move a circle in a line say after 3 sec. I am using JS to dynamically draw a circle and move it and setTimeout for time delay. when i load the page the circle appears after 3 sec but in meantime has traveled some distance on the line (it was supposed to start from the beginning of the line i.e (30,y1)). I cannot figure out where i went wrong.
here are relevant codes:

train.js

```
    function RunTrain(x,y,desti,time,r)
     {
        var xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        var C=document.createElementNS(xmlns,"circle");
        C.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",x);
        C.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",y);
        C.setAttributeNS(null,"r",r);
        C.setAttribute("style","stroke-width:1;stroke:blue;fill:skyblue");

        var animate=document.createElementNS(xmlns,"animate");
        animate.setAttribute("attributeName","cx");
        animate.setAttribute("attributeType","XML");
        animate.setAttribute("from",x);
        animate.setAttribute("to",desti);
        animate.setAttribute("dur","2s");
        animate.setAttribute("begin","0s");
        animate.setAttribute("repeatCount","1");
        animate.setAttribute("fill","freeze");

        C.appendChild(animate);
        document.getElementById("id1").appendChild(C);
        //id1 is the id of svg tag
     }
```

call.js

```
setTimeout(function(){ RunTrain(30,y1,Mlx2,5,10); },3000);
```

demo.html

```
<svg height = 5000 width = 5000 id="id1">  </svg>   
<script src="/static/train.js"></script>
<script src="/static/call.js"></script>
```

Note: it is a part of django project. I am using mozilla.

**Edit**
This animateTransform is also causing trouble even on calling beginElement on it.

```
 var animateTransform=document.createElementNS(xmlns,"animateTransform");
    animateTransform.setAttribute("attributeName","transform");
    animateTransform.setAttribute("attributeType","scale");
    animateTransform.setAttribute("dur","2s");
    animateTransform.setAttribute("begin","3s");
    animateTransform.setAttribute("from","0 0");
    animateTransform.setAttribute("to","160 "+ y1);
    animateTransform.setAttribute("fill","freeze");
```

Comment: Did you mean `setInterval`?

Comment: sorry, typing mistake but i used both setTimeout and setInterval. none work

Comment: The document has a timeline, time passes but you always begin animation at 0s

Comment: but wasnt setTimeout supposed to execute RunTrain after 3 sec? so how will it execute at t=0sec?

Comment: @RobertLongson  i tried it and you are correct. can you please answer my above questions.

Comment: I don't really understand your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation timer for SMIL animation begins ticki ng when the SVG document is created.  So if you say `begin="0s"` that means the animation should start when the document is first created.  In your case, that is when the `<svg>` is added to the DOM. Not when you add the `<circle>` and `<animate>` elements three seconds later.  So the animation is begins as if you were already running for three seconds.

The simplest fix for your code is to set `begin="indefinite"` and start the animation running after you add the elements. You do that by calling `beginElement()`. See the demo below.

```js
function RunTrain(x,y,desti,time,r)
{
    var xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var C=document.createElementNS(xmlns,"circle");
    C.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",x);
    C.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",y);
    C.setAttributeNS(null,"r",r);
    C.setAttribute("style","stroke-width:1;stroke:blue;fill:skyblue");

    var animate=document.createElementNS(xmlns,"animate");
    animate.setAttribute("attributeName","cx");
    animate.setAttribute("attributeType","XML");
    animate.setAttribute("from",x);
    animate.setAttribute("to",desti);
    animate.setAttribute("dur",time);
    animate.setAttribute("begin","indefinite");
    animate.setAttribute("repeatCount","1");
    animate.setAttribute("fill","freeze");

    C.appendChild(animate);
    document.getElementById("id1").appendChild(C);
    //id1 is the id of svg tag
  
    animate.beginElement();
}

var y1 = 30;
var Mlx2 = 400;

setTimeout(function(){ RunTrain(30,y1,Mlx2,5,10); },3000);
```

```html
<svg height="5000" width="5000" id="id1"></svg>
```

Comment: what should i do if i have AnimateTransform in `RunTrain()` too? animate.beginElement doesnt work then

Comment: You need to also call `beginElement()` on the new animateTransform element. Are you doing that?  If yes, then try asking a new question with your new code.

Comment: please check the question edit. I think there is problem with `begin` attribute. I have tried using indefinite but that wont work.

Comment: Please create a fiddle with what you have tried, so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: i solved my problem.just needed to do `animateTransform.beginAt()`. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your function initially and then also call it again in a setTimeout. Something like this would work:

```
RunTrain(<initial args>)
setInterval(() => RunTrain(<args for future>), 3000)
```